# (Beginners Java) Why is my array null?

Tags: java, arrays, null

Here's my method:

```
public int randomIntegers() {
    array = new int[20];
    Random r = new Random();

    for(i =0; i<20; i++) {
        int intRandom = r.nextInt(1000);
        if (intRandom >= 100) {
            array[i] = intRandom;       
        }
    }
    return array[i];
}
```

Println:

```
System.out.println(array[i]);
```

And when I use println in the main method, I get a NullPointerException. Have honestly tried to conceptually understand why this isn't working, to no avail.

Comment: Show us what are you trying to print, or your main method and also define the values of size , max and min

Comment: And you are returning the last element of the array if you want to return complete array then return the reference

Comment: Try to print the value of `i` before printing. And also - are you initializing the array before calling the `print` statement?

Comment: Where is `i` declared? I think you need to show the whole file.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to return an integer, not the entire array. The integer is not even valid because you are trying to return the integer after the last integer in the array.

I'm guessing you want to return the entire array to your main method, if so you need to change the method signature to return an array, and change the return statement, as such:

```
public int[] randomIntegers() {
   //code....
   return array;
}
```

On another note, you don't always fill your array with generated integers. A slot will, when the random number generated is < 100 (so about every tenth time), not be filled and thus have a value of 0 in the slot of the int.

Comment: primitive default will be set - `0` in case `if` is not satisfied. Please correct me if I am not.

Answer (score 0):

If the code in your question is a true reflection of the code you are actually running, then the only plausible explanations for

```
     System.out.println(array[i]);
```

throwing an NPE are:

- You haven't called `randomIntegers()` (yet).
- The `array` you are printing is a *different variable* to the `array` that you are assigning to in the `randomIntegers` method.

If that doesn't explain things, please update your question with your *entire* program and the stacktrace.